# get only one division center in one row class using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have one class row in my web page and in that class i have one division but i want to display that division in center however m not able to done this.
this is my simple row class.

```
      <div class="row">
      <div id="left" class="col-md-6">
       <div id="leftin" class="col-md-6"></div>
       </div>
    <div id="right" class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
```

and my css

```
 #left
{

 height: 150px;
}
#leftin
{
 background: url(news_image_04.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
#right
{
  background: url("news_image_03.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 150px;
 }
```

i want to center leftin division under left division

Comment: On leftin use class="col-md-12 text-center" and on left add class text-center also. Or on leftin use class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3". Try both.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the float none of this.

```
#leftin {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("news_image_04.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / 100% 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: none; /* make the float none */
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
 #left
{

 height: 150px;
 border:1px solid red;
}
#leftin {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("news_image_04.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / 100% 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: none; /* make the float none */
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


#right
{
  background: url("news_image_03.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 150px;
   border:1px solid purple;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
      <div id="left" class="col-md-6">
       <div id="leftin" class="col-md-6"></div>
       </div>
    <div id="right" class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For leftin remove class="col-md-6" and add width 50%

```
<div class="row">
      <div id="left" class="col-md-6">
       <div id="leftin"></div>
       </div>
    <div id="right" class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>

#leftin
{
     background: url(news_image_04.jpg) no-repeat;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     height: 150px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add class to `col-md-offset-3` div with id leftin
like below

```
<div id="leftin" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"> </div>
```

Updated to your example

```css
#left
{

 height: 150px;
}
#leftin
{
 background: url(news_image_04.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
#right
{
  background: url("news_image_03.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 150px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div id="left" class="col-md-6">
       <div id="leftin" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"></div>
       </div>
    <div id="right" class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
```